# Google Cloud PHP my admin is not getting connected with ssh

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I've been trying connecting my `PHP my admin` via ssh Client tool putty, but my URL gets redirected to my `website URL` from 127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin to `example.com:8080/phpmyadmin` which throws me the following error 
`For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname.`

Answer (score 0):

This is a built-in security feature. In order to access your server using SSH using Putty, you must create an SSH tunnel to route your request.

I found this guide that explains in detail how to get this set up:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Hi @Oliver Aragon, the connection works fine, the actual problem is when I try to connect it with `127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin`  it redirects me to my website `www.example.com:8888/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using Google App Engine Flexible, Standard or a Compute Engine instance?

Comment: Standard or a Compute Engine instance I think. I started it by creating a bucket

Comment: Hi @TheLawliet94,
Could you check if you have any entry in your `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts ` file that could be mapping it?

Comment: @DavidGomez I come this far how I map it?