# For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname

Tags: google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin, putty

[image]
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/

**I have problem in accessing PHPMyAdmin via putty**

I use putty and connect it successfully as you see in the screenshot.
but when I type the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin
it gives me the massage :

> *For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname.*

I follow below article:
[Google Cloud PHP my admin is not getting connected with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201530/google-cloud-php-my-admin-is-not-getting-connected-with-ssh)
Tey give me the bitnamy reference what I use to connect putty

This below article:
[Bitnami: For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60520808/bitnami-for-security-reasons-this-url-is-only-accessible-using-localhost-127)

Told me to almost the same thing but there is a solution :

> Solved by modifying the configuration file.

Where it the location of the configuration file they didn't mention it.

My point is how I get rid of this security warning and go to my PHPMyAdmin file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me in my Ubuntu 18.04 was modified /opt/drupal/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf:

I'm based on [Can't connect to phpmyadmin in Bitnami instance hosted by AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327531/cant-connect-to-phpmyadmin-in-bitnami-instance-hosted-by-aws)

Main changes being:

```
Allow from all
```

and

```
Require all granted
```

The outcome is:

```
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
Require all granted
</IfVersion>
```

After modified you have to restart services:
/opt/drupal-8.8.5-1/ctlscript.sh restart